# Mule 4 : Database : How to pass a SQL query as a variable in database "Query Text"?

Tags: mule4

Scenario : I have formed a SQL query and stored it in a variable `vars.query`
I want to use this variable in the DATABASE SELECT component in the SQL QUERY TEXT window.

To do that, I passed `vars.query` in the Query text, and ran the application. The application gets deployed successfully but in runtime fails with the DB : EXCEPTION , expected SQL query but found DDL

I have tried the following approach:

in QUERY text added `:query` and in the Input Parameters refereed the

```
{
    'query' : vars.hierarchyQuery
}
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.ErrorBuilder$ErrorImplementation
{
  description=Query type must be one of [SELECT, STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL] but query '?' is of type 'DDL'
  detailedDescription=Query type must be one of [SELECT, STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL] but query '?' is of type 'DDL'
  errorType=DB:BAD_SQL_SYNTAX
  cause=org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.BadSqlSyntaxException
  errorMessage=-
  childErrors=[]
}
```

Comment: Please add the database operation in XML (text please) to your question, so we can see how the variable is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing this : In the Query Text window refer to the sql query containing variable as #[vars.query]

Comment: Am facing an issue when the select query with where the condition was passed through a variable.

Select * from Tablename --> This is working 
Select * from Tablename where colomn1=columnValue --> This is throwing an error as below

Unknown column 'columnValue' in 'where clause'

Comment: For where condition you will have to declare the items and their values in the Input Parameters box. So if you have query with where condition declare variables like where column1=:column1 and in the input box below the query section declare {"column1" : variable value}

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by adding `$(vars.query)` to 'SQL Query Text' field

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.10/database-connector-select